# Laravel - Prevent errors from being shown in console

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm doing an ajax request and if the validation fails, the user is presented with an error message.

However, the user can also see the error message in console. For example, if the user doesn't complete one of the fields, in console, this is what it shows:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity)

I do not want them to see the error. How can I prevent them from seeing errors like such and also other error in console, like 501 errors and stuff. I just simply want to display an alert saying "An error occurred". I don't want to show anything in console.

My current AJAX code:

```
(function ($) {
        $('#settingsForm').submit(function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'JSON',
                url: '/settings',
                data: $('#settingsForm').serialize(),
                beforeSend: function () {

                },
                success: function (data) {
                    message(data);
                },
                error: function (data) {

                    if (data.status === 422 ) {

                        var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
                        errorsHtml = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><ul>';
                        $.each(errors, function (index, value) {
                            errorsHtml += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
                        });
                        errorsHtml += '</ul></div>'
                        $('#status_settings').html(errorsHtml);
                    }

                }
            })
            ;

            e.preventDefault();
        })
        ;
    })
    (window.jQuery);
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to hide these error messages? I would think, if it is even possible, it would require some special permissions to be requested, or via a browser extension.

Comment: possible on dataType: 'JSON'. Do you get the input on the field?
Test with `Input::get('YOUR_INPUT_FIELD')`

Comment: Instead of showing, I watch to catch the error and show an error alert instead. I get input on the field, yes

Comment: Sorry i miss understood your question, so you want to suppress error code in browser console. Yes you can access chrome console object through javascript, but whether you can suppress the error, that will need some guy who have experience on this particular part.

Comment: You can’t. These are HTTP errors. Any one can view them via the console.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you are using Laravel Form Request validation which sends a 422 status code for failed validation along with errors in case if AJAX form submission. There are two things you can do now to change the status code and remove the error message ( only in this case ) from the console:

1. Override the response function in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php and change the status code to 200 in your new function. Copy the function from there and paste it in Request class in app/Http/Requests/Request.php.
   Change the following line

   ```
   return new JsonResponse($errors, 422);
   ```

   to something like this:

   `$errors['status'] = 'error';
   return new JsonResponse($errors, 200);`
2. Instead of using Form Request Validation, create a [Validator](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#controller-validation) instance for validation in your controller functions and return [JSON response](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/responses#other-responses) upon failed validation with 200 status code.

Comment: Just what I wanted. Doing #2 did the job. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! I've updated my answer to show an example on how to do this using Form Request Validation.

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks like you are using error code 422 for the validation error. These errors are displayed in the console. What you have to do is just return 200 for success and validation error. Since validation error means the request was successful, only the data was error so you should always use 200 code for this.

What you can do instead is to create another variable maybe response like below and check the status in the success message (if it was successful or there occured a validation error). Other error codes can still be handled in error closure.

```
success: function (data) {

    if(data.response == 'success')
       message(data);

    else if(data.response == 'validation-error'){
        var errors = $.parseJSON(data.responseText);
        errorsHtml = '<div class="alert alert-danger"><ul>';
        $.each(errors, function (index, value) {
            errorsHtml += '<li>' + value + '</li>';
        });
        errorsHtml += '</ul></div>'
        $('#status_settings').html(errorsHtml);
    }

 },
```